# Im not create Neo4j with multiple port

Tags: neo4j

how to setup Neo4j on Ubuntu with different ports please any one explain me step by step .

Thanx In Advance

Comment: This is not detailed enough. Please tell us what you are trying to do, what documentation you read etc etc

Comment: I  want Creating neo4j multiple port Like 9200, 8081,8181 but neo4j only taking default port 7474-7687  So How to do reslove . please Explain

Comment: I believe a Google search like "configure Neo4j ports" would have led to the results you want. Were your searches unsuccessful?

Comment: Bro Im also trying before 1 Week but not geeting clear . so plz can you sujjest me .

Answer (score 0):

On Neo4j side,

- 7474 is the default port for HTTP
- 7473 is the default port for HTTPS
- 7687 is the default port for Bolt

There are a few more and can be changed as explained [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/ports/).